# mediarecorder.audiosource.voice_call not working in xiaomi redmi error

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I have tried to record call with **AudioSource.VOICE_CALL** in Android. It is working on most of devices like (Samsung S3 ,Samsung S4 , Nexus ) but in **redmi xiaomi 1s** it is not

Below is snippet of code that I used :

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.reset();
recorder.setAudioSource(audiosource);
recorder.setOutputFormat(audioformat);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);           
recorder.setOutputFile(recording.getAbsolutePath());
recorder.setOnInfoListener(this);
recorder.setOnErrorListener(this);

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        recorder = null;
        return; 
    }

recorder.start();
```